# How to set TYPO3 7 metatags from TypoScript RECORDS?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.x

I'm trying to override the `page.meta.og:title` in `TYPO3 7.5` with a `TypoScript` `RECORDS` object.

The following `TypoScript` snippet does not seem to work unfortunately:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_myext_pi1|article > 0]

    temp.newsTitle = RECORDS
    temp.newsTitle {
        dontCheckPid = 1
        tables = tx_myext_domain_model_article
        source.data = GP:tx_myext_pi1|article
        source.intval = 1
        conf.tx_myext_domain_model_article = TEXT
        conf.tx_myext_domain_model_article {
            stdWrap.field = title
            stdWrap.wrap = |
        }
    }

    # Overrides the template pageTitle
    page.10.variables.pageTitle >
    page.10.variables.pageTitle < temp.newsTitle

    # Overrides the meta og:title   
    page.meta.og:title >
    page.meta.og:title < temp.newsTitle

[global]
```

I get:

```
<meta name="og:title" content="RECORDS">
```

While the override of the page title works for me.

Are there any ways to achieve this with TypoScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was to quick with posting my question :)

It could be achieved by using the register, here is a example:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_myext_pi1|article > 0]

    page.9 = LOAD_REGISTER
    page.9 {
        newsTitle.cObject = RECORDS
        newsTitle.cObject {
            dontCheckPid = 1
            tables = tx_myext_domain_model_article
            source.data = GP:tx_myext_pi1|article
            source.intval = 1
            conf.tx_myext_domain_model_article = TEXT
            conf.tx_myext_domain_model_article {
                stdWrap.field = title
                stdWrap.wrap = |
            }
        }
    }

    page.10.variables.pageTitle >
    page.10.variables.pageTitle = TEXT
    page.10.variables.pageTitle {
        data = register:newsTitle
    }

    page.meta.og:title >
    page.meta.og:title {
        attribute = property
        override.data = register:newsTitle
    }

[global]
```

Answer (score 3):

RECORDS only works within a cObject.
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/ContentObjects/Records/Index.html

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_myext_pi1|article > 0]
    page.meta{
        og:title {
        attribute = property
            stdWrap.cObject = RECORDS
            stdWrap.cObject {
                source = {GP:tx_myext_pi1|article}
                source.insertData = 1
                tables = tx_myext_domain_model_article
                conf.tx_myext_domain_model_article= TEXT
                conf.tx_myext_domain_model_article.field = title
            }
        }
[global]
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's your ext what prevents you from adding it directly within action instead of manipulating with some weird TS? ;)

```php
public function showAction($article) {
    $ogTitle = trim(htmlentities($article->getTitle()));
    $GLOBALS['TSFE']->getPageRenderer()->addMetaTag('<meta name="og:title" content="' . $ogTitle . '">');

    // ... rest of action
}
```

Also take a look to Georg Ringer's [`News`](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/news) extension to see how he uses `metaTagViewHeplper` (actually he's doing the same but in VH) - you can use it to collect other `og` tags on the view like `og:image` and others.

**Edit:**

(*More about preventing duplicated entries*)

Keep in mind that duplicated `meta` combinations *it's not a bug, it's a feature* according to [OGP Arrays spec](http://ogp.me/#array) ;) Actually fact that you can not declare two same meta tags with TypoScript is a bug, reason? TypoScript is not a programming language, it's just configuration table (array to be strict). As we know in PHP in associative array later key overrides earlier. While we're in topic of `og:*` metas we need to remember that sometimes they are repeated per page and it's perfectly valid, i.e: `og:image`.

You as a programmer has much more power within your action than in TS, even if you are using some *ready-to-use* ext which fills `og:title` from the `pages` records, nothing prevents you from discarding it with ... simple trick in TS, in your TS add a condition:

```
[globalVar = GP:tx_myext_pi1|article > 0]
  page.meta.og:title >
[end]
```

and then make sure that you're adding it in your `showAction` as showed at the beginning.

Finally this way you do not need to make expensive lookup from TS site for each model that has a single view (believe me I know what that means)

BTW, I agree that there should be solid API for this, but I wrote some ext for one of my project for these things, that was matter of hours not even days, if I'll find it, I'll publish it to TER.

Comment: Your code does not prevent duplicated entries of the same metatag name and still needs TypoScript to get this fixed. Besides that your code can't override my template title and does not work when you deal with 3th party extensions.

Comment: I agree that there should be a solid api for it.

Comment: I understand your explanation and appreciate your time as well but the question is about "how it can be done with TypoScript's object RECORDS" and less how it can be done in extension development (that part I already knew) ;)

However I think this is still not the best solution at all since there is no proper way how metatags (like description and keywords) are being rendered in TYPO3 I like the `ViewHelper` solution which gives me the possibility to add metatags without changing code in 3th party extensions.

Comment: I understand your thougts about TypoScript but I'm still stuck to use it since I can't provide my template title by using a ViewHelper here. And TypoScript is way more than a configuration language, like to see how it's being used in TS2 (flow/neos).